# Melanie {starts/will start} school tomorrow

Tags: present-tense, future-constructions

> "Melanie starts school tomorrow."

or

> "Melanie will start school from tomorrow".

1st sentence is simple present tense and the 2nd one is simple future tense, so my question instead of simple present tense can we use simple future tense?

Comment: There are lots of questions already asking about the use of the present simple to speak of the future. Can you check these answers and [edit] to explain why they don't answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there tomorrow or Will there be tomorrow?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37826/is-there-tomorrow-or-will-there-be-tomorrow)

Comment: [What is acceptable]. What will be acceptable to future generations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I will start my course ..." Or "I start my course ..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119639/i-will-start-my-course-or-i-start-my-course)

Answer (score 1):

> Melanie starts school tomorrow.

and

> Melanie will start school tomorrow.

are both correct. However, it is very common using present to express future, so your first example is the more acceptable.

---

However, there is another problem I want to emphasize:

> Melanie will **start** school **from tomorrow**.

is incorrect, because there is no match between **start** and **from tomorrow**:

- **start**: refers to a specific **moment in time** (defined or undefined);
- **from tomorrow**: refers to the **period of time** starting tomorrow.

So if you remove "from", you get a correct sentence again.